# Multiple monitor setup using only onboard graphics

Tags: multiple-monitors

Quick question for anyone that can answer this.

Can I connect 3 monitors using only on-board graphics. There are 2 display port and a vga on the mother board and currently dual display is setup using both display port.

Realistically I am not looking for a true 3rd monitor but rather that the 2nd monitor is duplicated on the 3rd monitor; is this possible?

I was thinking about trying a display port splitter and having the second and 3rd monitors both run off of a single display port using the splitter.

Figured it was easier to ask then spend about $100 for the splitter and a long cable to try and find out it won't work.

Edit for clarification: The setup trying to be used  is 2 actual monitors with the 3rd screen being a TV to do presentations. Leadership/managers/execs want the first screen to be able to do work and have a "private" screen so to speak  while hosting presentations on the 2nd screen, allowing them to see it from the monitor as opposed to also needing to control the presentation from the TV/3rd screen, which would be duplicated on the 3rd screen.

While I can think of quite a few alternatives in designing a new system to incorporate this need I am being told to do this, if possible in any way, with the equipment in hand minus potentially a few new cables.

I have also considered buying a few "cheap" graphics cards to allow for a better solution and recommended this but as of yet I am not seeing willingness to use this solution.

Comment: nullterminatedstring - considered that but it seemed to be talking more about daisy chaining than DP splitting.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer talks about daisy chaining but it also suggests the [Matrox TripleHead ToGo](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/?productTabs=1#close) for using one DisplayPort port for two monitors, which should answer your question, and it states that real signal splitting isn't supported by DisplayPort. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: nullterminatedstring - Nothing wrong per say my only concern with that specific solution is the answer states that it tricks the computer into only seeing 1 screen and spreads the image across. That leads me to believe if I used that I would essentially get 3 separate screens instead of 2 independent screens with the 2nd screen duplicated on the 3rd screen.

Thus using it on screen 2 and 3 won't work for the desired result and using it on screen 1 and 2 won't allow me to duplicate only screen 2 as the computer would only see 1 screen to duplicate.

Comment: P.S. my hope was that given my concerns with the Matrox TripleHead Togo and the fact that the specified thread, and other similar threads, were old (2011 for the thread linked) that some progress may have been made in the past 6ish years or new products supporting splitting my have come about.

Comment: You're right it isn't a duplicate, the [ICY BOX Splitter IB-SPL1023](http://www.raidsonic.de/products/adapter_multidocking/special_adapter/index_en.php?we_objectID=3664) might be what you want.It claims to be able to duplicate, switch or extend the DisplayPort port depending on what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen this when looking for possible splitters. I will give it a try and respond back when I have an answer as to whether or not it works. Either way if you want to add that as an actual answer I will absolutely give you the best answer (if you want the points on here or anything)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, but try the adapter first before marking my answer as the "best answer" ...

Comment: It depends on your chip and board. Some recent Intel integrated graphics does support 3 motor.

Comment: One thing of a splitter I'm not sure about is HDCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ICY BOX Splitter IB-SPL1023](http://www.raidsonic.de/products/adapter_multidocking/special_adapter/index_en.php?we_objectID=3664) might be what you want.It claims to be able to duplicate, switch or extend the DisplayPort port depending on what you want/need.